# RPI Python subprocess.check_output - not returning

Tags: python

I'm trying to set the time from python, It is almost working, except than program is never returning back to Python.
The time is set/change correct, but after that nothing happens. The last 3 lines is not carried out.
What is wrong ?

```
klokken = "2017-11-12 09:50:00"
print("DS3231 kl:\t\t%s" % klokken)
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "date", '--set', klokken])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print("date error")
print("Time and date is set")
```

Comment: This works for me.. are you running this locally? or on remote machine?

Comment: locally - and it is working in Terminal mode wo any problems

Comment: I just tryed it in seperated test file, where it running wo any problems. So it most have something to do whit my master program. And I need to close the shell program to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's woorking. I moved the import subprocess to the top of the program.

It maybe because it need some time to initialize.